# How to sent two shipping requests to carrier?

Tags: shipping

I have installed simple [multi-warehouse extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/multi-warehouse-inventory-by-gaboli.html).its only manage inventory.

Now i created two warehouses A & B.and Product-X quantities in A-10 & in B-15.

Now if i ordered Product-X  with 25 quantities its reducing quantity from both A & B.

Now My requirement is I need to send two requests to carrier.

1st request: origin-A to customer shipping address quanity-10

2nd request:origin-B to customer shipping address quantity-15.

Now I want to display both requests in front end.and customer should select two shipping methods to complete the order.

any idea ? how to start this requirement.i'm thinking i need to repeat request in

```
 Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address requestShippingRates(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item_Abstract $item = null)
```

**Update**

**Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address**

```
public function requestShippingRates(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item_Abstract $item = null)
    {
         $titems=$this->getAllItems();

        if(!$item)
        {
            $warehouses=array();
           foreach($titems as $titem)
           {

                $kitem=clone $titem;

                $stockCollection = Mage::getModel('exinent_warehouse/stock')
                    ->getCollection()            
                    ->addFieldToSelect(array('location_id', 'qty'))                    
                    ->addFieldToFilter(
                        'qty',
                        array(
                            'gt' => '0'
                        )
                    )
                    ->addFieldToFilter('product_id', $kitem->getProductId());       


            foreach($stockCollection as $res)
             {
                if($kitem->getQty()>=$res->getQty())
                {
                   $citem=clone $kitem;
                   $citem->setQty($res->getQty());//->save();              
                   $warehouses[$res->getLocationId()][]= $citem;
                   $loc[]=$res->getLocationId();

                   $kitem->setQty($kitem->getQty()-$res->getQty());//->save();

                }

             }
           }
        }

        $i=0;
       foreach($warehouses as $warehouse)
       {

        /** @var $request Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request */
        $request = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_request');
        $request->setAllItems($item ? array($item) : $warehouse);
        $warehouseinfo=Mage::getModel('exinent_warehouse/location')->load($loc[$i]);

        $request->setOrigCountry($warehouseinfo->getData('country_id'));
        $request->setOrigPostcode($warehouseinfo->getData('zipcode'));

        $request->setDestCountryId($this->getCountryId());
        $request->setDestRegionId($this->getRegionId());
        $request->setDestRegionCode($this->getRegionCode());
        /**
         * need to call getStreet with -1
         * to get data in string instead of array
         */
        $request->setDestStreet($this->getStreet(self::DEFAULT_DEST_STREET));
        $request->setDestCity($this->getCity());
        $request->setDestPostcode($this->getPostcode());
        $request->setPackageValue($item ? $item->getBaseRowTotal() : $this->getBaseSubtotal());
        $packageValueWithDiscount = $item
            ? $item->getBaseRowTotal() - $item->getBaseDiscountAmount()
            : $this->getBaseSubtotalWithDiscount();
        $request->setPackageValueWithDiscount($packageValueWithDiscount);
        $request->setPackageWeight($item ? $item->getRowWeight() : $this->getWeight());
        $request->setPackageQty($item ? $item->getQty() : $this->getItemQty());

        /**
         * Need for shipping methods that use insurance based on price of physical products
         */
        $packagePhysicalValue = $item
            ? $item->getBaseRowTotal()
            : $this->getBaseSubtotal() - $this->getBaseVirtualAmount();
        $request->setPackagePhysicalValue($packagePhysicalValue);

        $request->setFreeMethodWeight($item ? 0 : $this->getFreeMethodWeight());

        /**
         * Store and website identifiers need specify from quote
         */
        /*$request->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
        $request->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId());*/

        $request->setStoreId($this->getQuote()->getStore()->getId());
        $request->setWebsiteId($this->getQuote()->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
        $request->setFreeShipping($this->getFreeShipping());
        /**
         * Currencies need to convert in free shipping
         */
        $request->setBaseCurrency($this->getQuote()->getStore()->getBaseCurrency());
        $request->setPackageCurrency($this->getQuote()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrency());
        $request->setLimitCarrier($this->getLimitCarrier());

        $request->setBaseSubtotalInclTax($this->getBaseSubtotalInclTax() + $this->getBaseExtraTaxAmount());

        $result = Mage::getModel('shipping/shipping')->collectRates($request)->getResult();

        $found = false;
        if ($result) {
            $shippingRates = $result->getAllRates();

            foreach ($shippingRates as $shippingRate) {
                $rate = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_address_rate')
                    ->importShippingRate($shippingRate,$loc[$i]);
                if (!$item) {
                    $this->addShippingRate($rate);
                }

                if ($this->getShippingMethod() == $rate->getCode()) {
                    if ($item) {
                        $item->setBaseShippingAmount($rate->getPrice());
                    } else {
                        /**
                         * possible bug: this should be setBaseShippingAmount(),
                         * see Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Shipping::collect()
                         * where this value is set again from the current specified rate price
                         * (looks like a workaround for this bug)
                         */
                        $this->setShippingAmount($rate->getPrice());
                    }

                    $found = true;
                }
            }
        }
        $i++;
        }

        return $found;
    }
```

in **onepagecontroller**

```
public function saveShippingMethodAction()
    {
        if ($this->_expireAjax()) {
            return;
        }
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {

            $warehouses=$this->getRequest()->getPost('warehouses', '');
        foreach($warehouses as $warehouse)
        {
            $data[]= $this->getRequest()->getPost('shipping_method'.$warehouse, '');


            }
            $result= $this->getOnepage()->saveShippingMethod($data);

            // $result will contain error data if shipping method is empty
            if (!$result) {
                Mage::dispatchEvent(
                    'checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method',
                     array(
                          'request' => $this->getRequest(),
                          'quote'   => $this->getOnepage()->getQuote()));
                $this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->collectTotals();
                $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));

                $result['goto_section'] = 'payment';
                $result['update_section'] = array(
                    'name' => 'payment-method',
                    'html' => $this->_getPaymentMethodsHtml()
                );
            }
            $this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->collectTotals()->save();
            $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
        }
    }
```

in **onepage.php**

```
public function saveShippingMethod($shippingMethod)
    {
    if(is_array($shippingMethod))
    {

    if (empty($shippingMethod)) {
            return array('error' => -1, 'message' => Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Invalid shipping method.'));
        }       
        for($i=0;$i<count($shippingMethod);$i++)
        {
        $rate = $this->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getShippingRateByCode($shippingMethod[$i]);
        if (!$rate) {
            return array('error' => -1, 'message' => Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Invalid shipping method.'));
        }

        }

        $this->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()
            ->setShippingMethod(serialize($shippingMethod));

        $this->getCheckout()
            ->setStepData('shipping_method', 'complete', true)
            ->setStepData('payment', 'allow', true);

        return array();
    } else {
        if (empty($shippingMethod)) {
            return array('error' => -1, 'message' => Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Invalid shipping method.'));
        }
        $rate = $this->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getShippingRateByCode($shippingMethod);
        if (!$rate) {
            return array('error' => -1, 'message' => Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Invalid shipping method.'));
        }
        $this->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()
            ->setShippingMethod($shippingMethod)->setWarehouse($warehouse);

        $this->getCheckout()
            ->setStepData('shipping_method', 'complete', true)
            ->setStepData('payment', 'allow', true);

        return array();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This may be a better question for the developers of the module, as they are the ones that set this functionality up, and have the best access to the code. Apologies I can't answer your question.

Comment: Yes.we are trying to create extension only.but we dont know we are going in  right track or not

Answer (score 2):

> Now I want to display both requests in front end.and customer should select two shipping methods to complete the order.

I'm afraid this is not possible (not in a reasonable time frame at least).
Magento is designed to allow you to select one and only one shipping method.
But I have an idea.
Let's take them step by step.

First...making 2 requests.

I don't know how your carrier works or the API for that matter, but for all carriers, the price of the shipment is determined inside the `collectRates` method in the carrier model.
Most probably there is something in that method that makes a request to their API, sending data about the package and receiving a cost (or a set of costs).

You can modify the section that sends the request and send 2 of them instead and add up the prices you get as response. Yes add them up... see my idea for showing 2 methods.

Now...Selecting 2 shipping methods.
As I said, Magento is designed to work with selecting one shipping method.
How about combining the 2 shipping methods into 1.

Let's take the following scenario.
Your carrier gives you 2 prices for each request allowing the customer to choose one.
If you make 2 requests you will receive 2 * 2 = 4 prices.
You can make 4 shipping methods out of the 4 response you get.
Let's say you get this:

First request (15 items)

- price 10, Description: "We deliver in 2 days"
- price 20, Description: "We deliver in 1 days"

second request (10 items)

- price 8, Description: "We deliver in 2 days"
- price 16, Description: "We deliver in 1 days"

Combine these 4 prices into 4 shipping methods like this:

- price 18 (10 + 8). Description "10 products: We deliver in 2 days,  15 products: We deliver in 2 days"
- price 26 (10 + 16). Description "10 products: We deliver in 2 days,  15 products: We deliver in 1 day"
- price 28 (20 + 8). Description "10 products: We deliver in 1 day,  15 products: We deliver in 2 days"
- price 36 (20 + 16). Description "10 products: We deliver in 1 day,  15 products: We deliver in 1 day"

I hope I was clear in my description. Sorry if I chose the descriptions wrong and I hope you get the idea.

Unfortunately I don't have code for it. This is just how I would do it if faced with the same issue.

Comment: You're welcome, but the question is "Is it helpful at least a bit?"

Comment: helpful Marius.i will update my question  where we are

Comment: sorry forgot to  upvote Marius.